# jquery not working while submitting a form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, form-submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name").blur(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
      if ( $(this).val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$') ) 
    {
    $("#check_name").html("Good Name").hide();
    } 
else {
  $("#check_name").html("That's not a name.");
    }
```

It is inserting the values if it is wrong.It is not validating data when we submit a form.need help soon.

Comment: It is validating data on onblur event but not while submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually do validate on the form.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

After you have added jquery validation and set it up you can use

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<script>
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
       $("#myForm").validate();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with regex pattern `/pattern/g`

```
 $(this).val().match(/^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$/g)
```

Instead of

```
$(this).val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$')
```

**It is not validating?**

Because You are matching the string not with pattern

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name").blur(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
      if ( $(this).val().match(/^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$/g) ) 
    {
    $("#check_name").html("Good Name").hide();
    } 
else {
  $("#check_name").html("That's not a name.");
    }
```

Comment: It is validating data on onblur event but not while submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$(function(){
  $("#name").blur(function(e){
    var name = $(e.target).val();    
    if ( name.match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$') )  {
        $("#check_name").html("Good Name").hide();
    }else {
        $("#check_name").html("That's not a name.").show();
    }
    })
});
```

If you also want to see "Good Name", remove the .hide() ;)

Comment: It is validating data on onblur event but not while submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Use .test instead of .match to check for occurence. Also, is your regex correct, will it handle every name? Validate the regex somewhere on regex tester as well.

[Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606117/javascript-regexp-using-val-match-method](http://solution)

Comment: It is validating data on onblur event but not while submitting the form

Comment: It won't by default. You would have to bind the validation code to form submit event as well.

Comment: Can u show me adding it to my code...actually m new to it.